# Can every open ball in normed vector space be expressed as a union of open balls of FIXED radius?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In other words, let $B_r(x)$ be an open ball in normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and let $0<r'<r$. Can $B_r(x)$ be expressed as a union of open balls of radius $r'$?

My work so far: Let $y\in B_r(x)$. If $y\in B_{r'}(x)$, we are done.

If $r'\leq \|y-x\|<r$, let $s\in(\|y-x\|-r',r-r']$ and $y'=x+\frac{s(y-x)}{\|y-x\|}$. It follows that $B_{r'}(y')\subseteq B_r(x)$.

Finally, $y\in B_{r'}(y')$ iff $\|y-x\|>s-r'$ but why is $\|y-x\|>s-r'$? Is this result not correct (or my work)?

Comment: You need to fix the question.  "let $||x-y||$" ?

Comment: I was saying let $s\in(||y-x||-r',r-r']$

Comment: You left a sentence unfinished, with the dangling preposition "in", and you referred to something called $y$ without introducing it first. I'm guessing you meant "Let $y$ be a point in $B_r(x)$" $\qquad$

Comment: Note the typographical difference between $\|a\|\|b\|,$ coded as `\|a\|\|b\|`, and $||a|| ||b||,$ coded as `||a|| ||b||`. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$ U=\bigcup_{y\in B_{r-r'}(x)} B_{r'}(y).$$
If $z\in U$, then $z\in B_{r'}(y)$ for some $y\in B_{r-r'}(x)$, i.e.,
$$\|z-x\|\le \|z-y\|+\|y-x\|<r'+(r-r')=r,$$
so $z\in B_r(x)$.

On the other hand, if $z\in B_r(x)$, then let $$y=x+\frac{r-r'}r(z-x)=z+\frac{r'}{r}(x-z).$$ This makes $\|y-x\|=\frac{r-r'}{r}\|z-x\|<r-r'$ and $\|y-z\|=\frac{r'}r\|z-x\|<r'$, so $z\in B_{r'}(y)\in U$.

We conclude that $U=B_r(x)$